# Substates in UML State Diagram in DOT Format

Tags: uml, dot

I'm trying to generate a basic UML state diagram using the DOT format.  Here's my file at the moment:

```
digraph {
compound=true;
node [shape=Mrecord]
rankdir="LR"

subgraph cluster0
    {
    label = "D"
B [label = "B"]
C [label = "C"]
}
A [label = "A|entry / EnterA\nexit / ExitA"]

A -> B [   style="solid",label="X" ];
A -> C [   style="solid",label="X" ]; 
}
```

Running it through the [Erdos graphing engine](http://sandbox.kidstrythisathome.com/erdos/), it looks pretty much like I want except that I can't figure out how to make superstate D have rounded corners and the horizontal line and entry/exit conditions like state A does.

Is there a way to add these things to a DOT subgraph?

p.s. Graphviz says "[The record-based shape has largely been superseded and greatly generalized by HTML-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html)" but when I tried this, most engines gave me a pretty awful looking chart where the transition arrows didn't even come close to touching the states, which is why I'm doing the "obsolete" record-based shape instead of HTML.

Comment: Graphviz uses edges and nodes inside a graph or subgraph. You've made A a node as well as B and C. IMHO those cant be transformed into some kind of label inside D. You might get away with formating D like A and having B as well as C invisible inside D. That would decouple the rendering from the meaning tho. I can't imagine a clean solution.

Comment: This doesn't answer you question but may be useful: When doing UML diagrams I've been using "plantuml". It uses dot as a backend, and is easier to get nicer results. http://plantuml.com/state-diagram

Comment: do u want to make D as a state? true?

Answer (score 4):

A subgraph can have the style=rounded attribute so I guess this is what you want
(Also threw in the html label as a bonus):

```
digraph {
  compound=true;
  node [shape=Mrecord]
  rankdir="LR"

  subgraph cluster0 {
    label = "D"
    style = rounded 
    B [label = "B"]
    C [label = "C"]
  }
  A [label = <<table cellborder="0" style="rounded">
        <tr><td>A</td></tr>
        <hr/>
        <tr><td>entry / EnterA<br/>exit / ExitA</td></tr>
        </table>> 
     margin=0 shape=none]
  A -> B [style="solid" label="X"];
  A -> C [style="solid" label="X"]; 
}
```

[image]